# How to Save Multipart Form in Grails; Text and File Upload

Tags: grails, multipart

I'm trying to submit a form entry with an uploaded file, but I can't seem to get the controller to save the data properly.

Essentially, I want to post a caption and the uploaded source in one form.

An example of my domain class:

```
class Image {
    String caption
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpated
    String source
}
```

I don't how to store the source file and save the entry.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
def upload () {
    def f = request.getFile('source')
    f.transferTo(new File("/path/to/file.tmp"))
    return
}
def save () {
    upload()
    def img = new Image(params)
    img.save(flush: true)
    ...runtime exception...
}
```

File creation works, but obviously the details on saving the Image entry is incorrect.

Comment: which part are you stuck on?  It looks like you have a pretty good start.  Why not just return the file location from the upload method then set it on your Image domain object (while possibly re-thinking the use of an absolute file location so you can configure different paths in different environments).  At that point it seems like you're very close to having everything working.

Comment: I found out what my problem was. My database plug-in wasn't installed, d'uh! Details....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this question answered. The problem was not Grails, but the tiny detail of me failing to install the plug-in necessary to insert data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

See this source code [Grails file upload example](https://github.com/cavneb/FileUploader) or this presentation [Uploading files with Grails](http://www.slideshare.net/cavneb/upload-files-with-grails).

Hope this helps